# Answerer's username will not show in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am fairly new to Rails 4, and I am creating a Q&A site similar to Stack Overflow.

I have a question page much like the one on Stack Overflow. The question part is working, and then I have answers, which are working too, HOWEVER, I want to be able to have the answerer's name next to their answer.

I am pretty sure I have the controller, model and view set up properly. I have reset the database but it still comes up with errors.

Here's my code:

```
#Answers_controller.rb create action
def create
    @answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)
    @answer.user_id = current_user.username

    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@question], notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @answer }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

answer.rb (model):

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question


  validates :body, presence: true
end

#Then in user.rb I have has_many :answers, has_many :questions
#Also in question.rb has_many :answers
```

answers/_answer.html.erb:

```
    <%= answer.username %>
    <%= answer.body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <% if current_user.present? && current_user == answer.user %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete Answer', [answer.question, answer],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
```

Then in questions/show:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <h3><%= @question.title %>
      <% if current_user.present? && current_user == @question.user  %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(@question) %></h3>
      <% end %>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
      <p><%= @question.description %></p>
        Asked by <%= @question.user.full_name %>
      <hr>
    </div>
    </div>

  <%= render "answers/form" %>
  <%= render @question.answers %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
      $(elem).wysihtml5();
    });

  })
</script>
```

Comment: You said it has errors, what are the errors?

Comment: @answer.user_id = current_user.username ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wrong here

```
@answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)
```

try

```
@answer = @question.answers.build(answer_params)
```

Explanaition: you build a new `answer` but do not refer it to `question` because according to [`has_many` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) it has `collection.build(attributes = {}, …)` not `collection.new(attributes)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am getting this error after making your corrections: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Comment: My guess is current_user is nil. Is anyone logged in?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that stand out:

```
#Answers_controller.rb create action
def create
   @answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)
   @answer.user_id = current_user.username # ???? should be current_user.id   ????
   # omitted
end
```

answers/_answer.html.erb

```
<%= answer.username %> # ???? you have no username field on your answer model ???
# ??? should be <%= answer.user.username %> ???
<%= answer.body %>
</p>

  # omitted
```